# AngularJS Factory adds $promise and $resolve to object but not sure how to resolve it correctly?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, single-page-application

I have a Factory in AngularJS, which serves as the bridge between my app and my back-end. When I try to add a DELETE function to my factory, it creates a weird URL which includes $promise and $resolved elements.

This is my AngularJS code. Basically: I am not sure where the $promise and $resolve statements are coming from (they should come from the getById statement right?)

This is the error:

```
DELETE http://localhost:8080/rest/speaker?$promise=%7B%7D&$resolved=false  415 (Unsupported Media Type)
```

1/ Controller

```
$scope.delete = function(id) {

    var speaker = SpeakerService.getById(id);

    SpeakerService.delete(speakerOrEmpty, function () {
        $log.log('saved at: ' + new Date());
        $route.reload();
    });

};
```

2/ Service

```
this.getById = function (id, callback) {
    return SpeakerResource.get({speakerId: id}, callback);
};

this.delete = function (data, callback) {
    SpeakerResource.delete(data);
}
```

3/ Factory/Resource

```
    {
        'delete': { method: 'DELETE' }
    })
```

What I have tried is to update my getById statement to this, but without success as I am still seeing the $resolved and $promise items in my DELETE request, although now they are set to TRUE.

```
DELETE http://localhost:8080/rest/speaker?$promise=%7B%7D&$resolved=true&id=5419e8…5c1cde009%22,%22name%22:%22x%22%7D&organizationId=541a3eee772fb8f5c1cde009  415 (Unsupported Media Type)  

$scope.delete = function(id) {

     var speakerOrEmpty = SpeakerService.getById(id, function (data) {

        speakerOrEmpty = data;

        SpeakerService.delete(data, function () {
            $log.log('saved at: ' + new Date());
            $route.reload();
        });
    });
};
```

Thank you so much for any help. It is much appreciated.